# Can a WordPress post display other Custom Posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom post type of "podcast." Each Podcast post collects the title, cover art, host name, etc. I have an HTML template for how these will be displayed.

Now what I'd like to do is create a handful regular posts that display these podcast posts. For example, "10 podcasts about history," which would display some of the history podcast entries.

Is this possible? If there's a plugin, I'd be open to that, but this also seems like something that a theme developer should be able to code.

Comment: Easily done with code. But, it is such a basic functionality and so easy to implement that I think there probably is a plugin to do this -  I saw one recently but as I don't know anything about it I would rather you do your own search of the the plugin repository. If you can't find anything I will give you the link but it is not a recommendation.

Comment: Themes are not supposed to include this kind of functionality. There may be a plugin however If you already have an html template then it should be fairly easy to create a shortcode, use get_posts and then return the html for each custom post returned.

Answer (score 1):

This works, you just have to figure how you want to 'rank' them, whether you going to have shortcode parameter to pass say the post type, so you can use it for multiple types

```
function get_p () {
        $custom_p = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'numberposts' => 10,
        ));
        $html = '';
        foreach (($custom_p) as $id=> $post) {
            $html .= '<li>'.$post->post_title.'</li>';
        }
        $html = '<ul>'.$html.'</ul>';
return ($html);
}

add_shortcode('get_p','get_p');
```